# Kill a specific event handle of a running process?

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to close a specific singleton handle associated with a process. The windows application "Process Explorer" allows you to do this but you need to select the process, then right click on the handle and select close. I am after a solution that will allow me to auto close the specific handle when the application is running.

I know I can get all processes and even kill a process by simply doing:

```
foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("your.exe"))
{
    p.Kill();
}
```

But how would I go about closing a handle attached the process and not the process itself?

Comment: Sysinternals process explorer is not a regular user mode application. It runs as a filter driver at the kernel mode level and has access to the operating system in a way that normal applications do not. However, you might be able to use  NtQueryInformationProcess or similar to dump the handles and NtDuplicateObject close them. good luck

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "specific handle"...and how exactly will you know that specific handle is...in order to kill it?

Comment: The handle is a singleton event with a static name for the process. Basically I am attempting to open multiple of the same applications at once and this is achieved by closing the event handle for singleton of the process.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I ended up using NtDuplicateObject though I had to write it in C++ :|

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using NtDuplicateObject as Michael suggested in the comments. It was a bit of a pain to implement but everything works as expected - thanks Michael!